# Trouble with Python API in ZED SDK Docker Container Setup

Tags: python, docker, stereolabs

Followed the official guide: https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/install-guide-linux/

And built a docker container from this image: https://hub.docker.com/layers/stereolabs/zed/3.2-devel-cuda9.0-ubuntu16.04/images/sha256-731e125758098e2cba840aefbcae9fe0848f90a9cab938a97a724af405c7717e?context=explore

(I have a docker container built from an official ZED SDK Docker Image)

I have ran the 'get_python_api.py' script to download what's necessary for the python api: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-python-api

I want to run a default svo_export.py script: https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-sdk/blob/master/recording/export/svo/python/svo_export.py

When I run it I get the following error and do not know how to fix it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "svo_export.py", line 212, in <module>
    main()
  File "svo_export.py", line 105, in main
    image_size = zed.get_camera_information().camera_configuration.resolution
AttributeError: 'pyzed.sl.CameraConfiguration' object has no attribute 'resolution'
```

CameraConfiguration class has an attribute 'resolution'
I'm not sure what's getting called incorrectly or if something else is going on.